# How is Coruscant supplied?

Tags: star-wars

Isaac Asimov gives significant attention in his  *Foundation* novels to how the Imperial capital and planet-wide city Trantor is maintained, discussing how entire planetary systems are needed simply to keep the populus feed.

Is anything similar mentioned in *Star Wars,* as to how the massive population of  Coruscant is kept fed and supplied day to day?